# If I change "have left" to "leave", does it change the meaning?

Tags: have

The original sentence is:

> Don't worry. We wouldn't **have** left without you?

What if I say:

> Don't worry. We wouldn't leave without you?

If I take out "have", will the meaning be changed?

Sorry, I'm not a native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these sentences are correct, and they are *almost* identical in meaning. Generally you could use either one.

"Wouldn't have left" refers to a specific event that is in the past, or that soon will be in the past. So you might use that if you have been waiting for someone to arrive, to reassure them that would have waited for them even if they had been late.

"Wouldn't leave" does not have any time attached to it, so you could use it in the same situation. But it has the additional meaning of reassuring them that if they are late in the future, you will also wait for them.